# How do you return an instance of a generic functional interface with a lambda?

Tags: java, generics, lambda

This doesn't work:

```
interface GenericFunctionalInterface {
    <T> void doSomething(T obj);
}
public class Foo {
    public final static GenericFunctionalInterface instance =
            (GenericFunctionalInterface) (a) -> {
                System.out.println(a);
    };
}
```

What is the correct syntax to instantiate `instance`?

**Note**

As the duplicate indicates, generic methods aren't able to be reduced to lambda expressions. But to add a bit to this, you *can* use the method address notation for a method that is or is not generic, provided that the method parameter's type is within the interface's generic type constraints.

E.g., we can write `instance = System.out::println;` because `T extends Object`, but we couldn't write `instance = Number::doubleValue;` because `T` does not extend `Number` (is not within the type constraints). Of course, if we wrote `<T extends Number> void doSomething(T obj)` we *could* define it as `Number::doubleValue;`.

See also [method reference capture](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html).

Comment: a `new GenericFunctionalInterface` would still work - did you try that?

Comment: Do you really need that interface method to be generic? You could simply write `void doSomething(Object obj);`... it would be the same (at least in your example)